# Add a comment to Instagram using Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to add a comment using Selenium and Python to Instagram posts. Specifically, the page has the following structure:

```
<textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..." placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

I tried with:

```
comment_button = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))

comment_button.send_keys("This is my comment")
comment_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

But it does not seem to be working; it does select the comment box but does not add the text

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on some instagram automation. Here's the code I have for commenting on a pic:

```
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

        commentSection = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", 
        commentSection)
        while(1 == 1):
            try:
                commentSection = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
                comment = comments[random.randint(0,numOfComments)]
                commentSection.send_keys(comment)
                commentSection.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                time.sleep(random.randint(3,4))
                break
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(random.randint(5,6))
```

feel free to check out my github repo for more help if you need it!
https://github.com/atloftus/IGActionAutomator